# C++ Pointer returning NULL

Tags: c++

Trying to update to a pointer from a function return. Just for background this is a template that acts like the stl vector. This is the returning function.

```
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//removes an item from the array
const T& remove(int pos)
{
    if(pos > cnt)
        pos = cnt;
    if(pos < 0)
        pos = 0;
    static T v;
    for(int i,k = 0; i < cnt; i++,k++)
    {
        if(i == pos)
        {
            v = element[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
            element[k] = element[i];
    }
    cnt--;
    return v;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

The pointer variable I am trying to update:

```
TVector<Member*> members;
Member* backmember;

backmember = members.remove(members.size()-1);
```

but backmember always returns null. I am sure I am missing something simple, just not sure what. Any ideas? Let me know if you have any questions and thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious, why can't you use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom instead of writing your own method.

Comment: `remove` returns a `const T&`. Your `backmember` takes a *pointer*, which is not the same thing as a reference. It also takes a non-`const` pointer. So that's two ways that this code is wrong. Are you sure this is the code in question? How does this compile, let alone return `NULL`?

Comment: Making a static copy of the object to return is a bad idea - it means two threads can't access *different* arrays at the same time. If you want to return the removed value, you should do it by value.

Comment: Yes I understand guys this is not my normal programming style. I had to fill in the functions and the return types have to match. I know the general rule is not to post assignment work to stackoverflow, but I knew it was something simple I was overlooking. This is what happens when you have a java instructor teaching C. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this initializes `i`:

```
for(int i,k = 0; i < cnt; i++,k++)
```

Try changing it to this and testing:

```
for(int i = 0,k = 0; i < cnt; i++,k++)
```

Comment: It's possible that the OP is under the impression that `int i,k = 0` initialises both `i` and `k`, whereas it only initialises `k` to 0. Of course, this is exactly what you've just said, I just wanted to state it more verbosely :)

Also, I personally find `for` loops containing multiple variables to be something to avoid wherever possible. They're too hard to read and understand at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i,k = 0; i < cnt; i++,k++)
```

`i,k` uses comma operator, which evaluate arguments in order, returning result of last one. So this means "declare i, then declare k and set it to 0"

`i` is not set. So most likely it get some large random value from memory and your loop never run